# Prevent JS window.open() from opening multiple windows across sessions

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem like this:

I've an HTML page , when I click a button it triggers a job on the backend server, the status on the page keeps getting refreshed and when it reaches a certain state a new window is opened through JS logic :

```
if (status) {
  window.open(URL, "_blank");
}
```

Now, my problem is if this page is open on multiple browsers, or even multiple instances of same browser, the window.open() is triggered across all of them when the status is true.

Is there a way to make the window open only from the page or browser session from where the job was triggered? Please help.